# NLTK corpus deployment Chatterbot Heroku

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I have a problem with my first Telegram chatbot, done with Chatterbot library.

My project is composed by:

- Procfile
- requirements (txt file)
- telegramtoken (txt file)
- runtime (txt file)
- nltk (txt file)
- botusers (csv file)
- magghybot (py file)
- Magghy (py file)
- conversations (yml file in a folder named lang)
- math_words (json file in a folder named lang)

I deployed my project on Heroku but there is this problem:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 275 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: 
remote: -----> Downloading NLTK corpora…
remote:  !     'nltk.txt' not found, not downloading any corpora
remote:  !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 47.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v5
remote:        https://magghy.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/magghy.git
   2cdd74d..254cbad  master -> master
```

I do not know what NLTK corpus to insert. My corpus to which the chatbot must refer are in the files named "conversations" (yml file) and "math_words" (json file).

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

Use this link instead of Heroku/python in buildpack:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
```

For example:

[image: Example buildpack configuration]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18549281)

Comment: @SeM Seems to me like the URL is a parameter to use when running the build, not something the OP posted to have us click on to read.